# Different membership receipts for 'New' and 'Active' members

Tags: civimember, contribution-page, system-workflow-messages

We send our donors once a year an email and ask them to become members. The email contains a link with a contact checksum that directly leads them to a contribution page, where they can select their membership and do the payments.

And our existing members we send a similar email and ask them to renew.

Both pages generate an email receipt using the template *Memberships - Receipt (on-line)* Is it possible to make a difference between the new and the already active members?

The CiviCRM version is 4.7.26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the smarty template the variable `$mem_status` is assigned. So it can be used to insert different text fragments in the template. Here is an example in code.

```
 {if $mem_status eq 'New'}
 Hello, you seem to be new so this is the text fragment for new members.
 {else}
 Welcome back - not new - so here is an active member text fragment.
 {/if}
```